# Value addition from a file's row

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

Suppose I have one file like:

```
apple  | red |   2
apple  | green |   3
orange  | yellow |  3
apple   | yellow | 1
```

Now I need following output as (irrespective of color value should get third number summed):

```
apple | red | 6
orange | yellow | 3
```

I tried something like below:

```
tail -n 4 $firstfile| while IFS=, read -r f2col1 f2col2
    do
        match1=$(echo $f2col2)
        fruit1=$(echo $f2col1)
        if [ "${fruit1}" == "${fruit1}" ]; then
            match3=`expr ${match3} + ${match1}`
```

which doesn't seem to be right after second addition.

Could somebody give me better idea?

Answer (score -1):

You could use awk for the entire operation

```
awk '{ arr[$1]+=$3; } END {for ( i in arr ) printf "%s | %d\n",i,arr[i];}'
```

Here is what each part does

1. `{ arr[$1]+=$3; }` adds the value to an associative array with the
   fruit name as the key
2. And in the end `{for ( i in arr ) printf "%s|%d\n",i,arr[i];}` prints each member of the array in the format you need